# How to get data from XML in TSQL using nodes?

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have such a table

```
declare @xml XML = '
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
  <props>
    <prop ns="ARM:" elem="_NoFilter">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="DAV:" elem="displayname">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Some text in it</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="DAV:" elem="getcontenttype">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">message/rfc822</value>
    </prop>
    <prop ns="DAV:" elem="creationdate">
      <value xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2017-01-02T09:38:28.1278078</value>
    </prop>
  </props>
  <Merchant xmlns="http://aaa.pl/">
     <Acceptor>dddd111</Acceptor>
  </Merchant>
</root>)'

select @xml as XmlData into #a
```

I try to get data from Acceptor but it dosn't work using NODES.
Could you help me how I should to this?

```
select 
    R.*,
    a = y.m.value('(Acceptor)[1]', 'varchar(50)')

from
    #a R
        outer apply R.XmlData.nodes('/root/Merchant') y(m)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the namespaces in the path:

```
;
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.xyz.de/activerepository/fileprops' as ns,'http://aaa.pl/'  as ns1)
select 
    R.*,
    a = y.m.value('(ns1:Acceptor)[1]', 'varchar(50)')

from
    #a R
        outer apply R.XmlData.nodes('/ns:root/ns1:Merchant') y(m)
```

for your new example:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://aaa.pl/'  as ns1)
select 
    R.*,
    a = y.m.value('(ns1:Acceptor)[1]', 'varchar(50)')

from
    #a R
        outer apply R.XmlData.nodes('root/ns1:Merchant') y(m)
```

Comment: I have to change a little my table. What if I dont have www.xyz.de. I try to replace it by www.w3.org bu it dosn't work

Comment: @dejzi as you removed the namespace for the root element, you don't need to qualify it in the path, you still need the namespace for Merchant and Acceptor though. I have update the answer for the new example.